# GNU Parallel and sshpass with server list in a loop

Tags: shell-script, openssh, gnu-parallel

With this loop we sequential update on all servers (server list = `consul members | grep awk {'print $2'} | cut -d ":" -f1`) the package `consul`.

```
for i in $(consul members | grep awk {'print $2'} | cut -d ":" -f1) ; do sshpass -p $PASSWORD ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -q root@$i "hostname && yum clean all && yum -y update consul && systemctl restart consul.service" ; done
```

We have over 1000 servers, so we wish to run the `sshpass` in parallel on 10 servers. I found [GNU Parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) for this task.

Howo use it with `sshpass` and make sure no server (server list) is done twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, `pssh` sounds like the better solution. If you must use `parallel` it should be fairly simple: pipe the hostnames one per line into a single command that uses `{}` as a placehold. Eg:

```
consul members | ... awk {'print $2'} | cut -d ":" -f1 |
parallel -j 10 sshpass -p "$PASSWORD" ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -q root@{} "hostname && yum clean all && yum -y update consul && systemctl restart consul.service"
```

Using `sshpass` should not make any difference. Test it first with a simple command such as just `hostname`.

Answer (score 1):

Use pssh with ssh host key authentication it's better

first, on the local box, as the user to connect with, do ssh-keygen to create a public key

then use ssh-copy-id to copy that public key to all the remote servers.  then do sometinhg like:

```
pssh -h <(consul members | grep awk {'print $2'} | cut -d ":" -f1) -o /tmp/update-consul-servers -i "yum clean all && yum -y update consul && systemctl restart consul.service"
```

Answer (score 0):

All, this is the working shell that prompt password in the script, do the require command and list which server is not authenticated.

for i in `cat /root/fahmi/up.list` ;
do 
  if ! sshpass -p 'password' ssh -n -T -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@"$i"; 
  then 
    echo "Server $i not accessible";
  fi
 sshpass -p 'password' ssh -T -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@"$i" <./command.sh

done

Comment: please fix formatting